# call value from TextView into a function in android

Tags: android, json, authentication

i have android app for login. I want to call the value input by user in a function which sets the data in json format the code i m using is

```
 public Object getName() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return "?" ;
}
```

In the return i want the value that user has entered.
the link of complete source code is 
http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

Comment: thanku for putting the question on hold

Comment: i already got the answer... and by one of u guys only....

Comment: and according to u question is unclear.... great.. try helping beginners a bit by thinking a bit for them and not putting their questsions on hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create getter and setter method for Object,

lets say,

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String twitter;

    //getters & setters....

}
```

Right click in that class  Source -> Generate Getter and Setter -> Select All then click OK

Comment: I am not able to find generate getter and setter where are they located? i am using eclipse

Comment: For development you are using Eclipse or any other environment??

Comment: found it . i am using eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the user name, the field `un`, inside the onClick event handler. Look at `un.getText()`

Answer (score 0):

First Set the entered Name in setmethod like this in onclick listener

//Inside onClick

```
   setName(un.getText().toString());



  public void setName(String name) {

    this.Name= name;
}

public Object getName() {

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return Name ;
 }
```

Comment: please go throught the code in link in the persons class it is not returning any value of get or set

Comment: Ya he mentioned //getters & setters.... like this na so you have to implement it. Got my point??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicating you can simple use un.getText().toString() or save username locally and use whenever you need.

If u really want to go with getName() function,use

```
    public Object getName() {
   return Name ;
 }
```

Comment: I am not able to understand where to put un.getText().toString()

Comment: U want it as a return from JSOn object or you want to access it somewhere in your app later?